# Facebook share in wp8 App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to share a message on Facebook in my windows phone App by clicking share button. when click share button , if user has not logged in to Facebook, first we redirect to log in screen and then need to ask permission to publish.

```
public partial  class FacebookLoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string uriToLaunch ;

    // Create a Uri object from a URI string 
    Uri uri = null;

    public FacebookLoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


     uriToLaunch = @"fbconnect://authorize?client_id={AppID}&
  scope=public_profile,publish_actions,read_stream&
  redirect_uri=msft-{ProductId}%3a%2f%2fauthorize";
            uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
        this.Loaded += FacebookLoginPage_Loaded;
    }

    private  void FacebookLoginPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DefaultLaunch();
    }

    // Launch the URI
    async void DefaultLaunch()
    {
        // Launch the URI
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

        if (success)
        {
            // URI launched
        }
        else
        {
            // URI launch failed
        }
    }
```

}

I used above code , but permission screen not appears for publish. Output was as follows.

[image]

I followed [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-for-windows-phone#login) and used an AppId, then it works well. I feel that there is special configuration in Facebook App side . Please help me If anyone have idea about it.

Comment: first of all dont publish your app id here!

Comment: It is not my app id. It is in the example that I mention

Comment: Can you show us a partial of facebook app configuration ?,you have to enable the permissions to side facebook app page